Common mode and differential mode filters order

In power supplies input filters the common mode block (typically a common mode choke) is usually placed first, and then the differential mode block follows. The image shows this structure.
Is there any reason for putting the common mode choke towards power input and differential mode filter towards the load?

If the differential filter were first, any common-mode noise picked up or coupled to it wouldn't be rejected.  So, putting the CM choke first makes sure that common-mode noise on anything else is rejected.

The reason is easy to see if you think of each node of the circuit as being connected to the chassis (or "GND") by a small "parasitic" capacitance.  Note that this GND node is not shown on your schematic.  If there is any common-mode voltage on any node in the circuit, then each of these parasitic capacitors will cause current to flow into this GND node, which is undesirable.
We want to reduce the current being coupled into GND by these parasitic capacitors, this is what the CM filter does.  If the CM filter is the very first filter the power input port sees, then all of the GND current through each parasitic capacitor must first pass through the CM filter.
However, if the DM filter is placed first, then there is nothing to reduce the GND current caused by those parasitic capacitors associated with the DM filter components.  And since DM filters can be quite large (since they have to carry the full load current of the rest of the circuit and the full voltage of the input power port) the parasitic capacitance they contribute can be quite large.
